# Can I pass a string to istream_iterator<int>

Tags: c++, stl

I have a string object that contains the value "1 2 3"

Can I use the istream_iterator to extract the values 1, 2 and 3

Comment: I'm not even sure what this is supposed to do. You say you "have a string that contains 1 2 3" but your code is completely different.

Comment: Yes. it is completely wrong. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: @ajay please accept an answer when you're satisfied. If you're not satisfied then ask for clarification or give us some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can, like this:

```
std::string str = "1 2 3";
std::vector<int> v;
std::istringstream iss(str);
std::istream_iterator<int> begin(iss), end;
std::copy(begin,end,back_inserter(v));
```

Comment: Or even how about `std::vector<int> v(begin, end);`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::istringstream`:

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iterator>

// ...
std::string s("1 2 3");
std::istringstream ss(s);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(ss), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "-"));
```

Comment: how come `istream_iterator<int>(istringstream(s))` doesn't work?